# Как добавить текст в конец файла? Java

Tags: java

Как сделать так, чтобы после каждого моего ввода данных файл не перезаписывался, а продолжал добавлять данные ниже?
Код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
List<ForClient> existsClients = read();
existsClients.add(createClients());
write(existsClients);
List<ForClient> clients = read();
System.out.println(clients);
}

public class ForClient extends CarData implements Serializable {
    private String fullName;
    private String email;
    private String country;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public ForClient() {
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Client [clientFullname=" + getFullName()
                + ", clientPhoneNumber=" + getPhoneNumber()
                + ", clientEmail=" + getEmail()
                + ", clientCountry=" + getCountry() + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что необходимо читать учебники, а не задавать совершенно базовые вопросы. Ценности для базы знаний от таких вопросов нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас чтение/запись заточена на один объект, а вы хотите иметь возможность добавлять, следовательно, нужно иметь возможность сохранять множество объектов.

```
public class Program {

    private final static String FILE_NAME = "1.txt";
    private final static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        List<ForClient> existsClients = read();
        existsClients.add(createClients());
        write(existsClients);
        List<ForClient> clients = filter(read(),
                (client1, client2) -> {
                    return client1.getFullName().compareTo(client2.getFullName());
                },
                client -> {
                    //return client.getFullName().equals("some_name");
                    return true;
                });
        System.out.println(clients);
    }

    public static List<ForClient> filter(List<ForClient> clients,
            Comparator<ForClient> comparator, Predicate<ForClient> predicate) {
        return clients.stream()
                .filter(predicate)
                .sorted(comparator)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static ForClient createClients() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ForClient client = new ForClient();
        System.out.println("Enter your fullname:");
        client.setFullName(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter your phone number:");
        client.setPhoneNumber(scanner.nextLine());
        return client;
    }

    public static void write(List list) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME))) {
            oos.writeObject(list);
        }
    }

    public static List read() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME))) {
            return (List) ois.readObject();
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы выводило значения (как было через getFullName)?

Comment: @May в классе ForClient переопределите метод toString()

Comment: спасибо! А можно ли сделать в данном случае фильтрацию и сортировку этих данных?

Comment: @May можно, конечно. Сортировка выполняется с помощью компораторов. Отфильтровать удобнее всего с применением стримов. Надо больше информации, как вы хотите фильтровать и сортировать

Comment: сортировка по нескольким полям (по возрастанию и убыванию). Отфильтровать нужно по имени и номеру

Comment: отредактировала код выше, чтобы было понятнее

Comment: @May в общем, если фильтры и сортировки всегда динамические, то можно сделать примерно так, как у меня в измененном ответе. Если, к примеру, сортировки определены (например один вариант - по имени, второй - по имейлу), то компараторы можно написать отдельными классами. Пример сортировки по имени я сделал, пример фильтра по имени добавил и закомментировал. Сортировать по номеру телефона - так себе идея. Номер телефона - цифры, но они записаны в переменной строчного типа, соответственно сортировка будет выполняться как сортировка строки , а не числа и результат будет странно выглядеть.

Comment: а если обеспечить модульными тестами все методы что есть, используя возможности JUnit, как это будет выглядеть? (используя фикстуры и параметризованные тексты)

Comment: @May это будет выгядеть точно также. а тесты так, как вы их напишите. junit - штука простая, как тапочек, материалов по ней тонна. нужно знать 3 аннотации и ассерт. что именно вызывает затруднения?

Comment: ассерты вызывают затруднения. Я могу сделать assertNotNull вовремя создания объектов класса?